# Before insert trigger prevents following INSERT INTO statements to execute

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a problem with the following sql code executed in MySQL Workbench 5.6. The table is orderly created, the trigger creation code is also run without errors. But when I try to run the both insert into statements I have an error Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'Pass' in 'field list'. If I run the last select statements it is also runned as expected!?

**I really can not imagine what is happening after running the trigger creation script!?**

If I do not run the triger creation code before the insert into statements they are executed as expected and the data is inserted in the columns.

/*TASK 15: Write a SQL statement to create a table Users. Users should have username,
 password, full name and last login time. Choose appropriate data types for the table fields.
 Define a primary key column with a primary key constraint. Define the primary key column 
as identity to facilitate inserting records. Define unique constraint to avoid repeating 
usernames. Define a check constraint to ensure the password is at least 5 characters long.
*/

```
 create table Users(
    UserID int auto_increment not null,
    Username nvarchar(50) not null,
    Pass varchar(100) not null,
    FullName nvarchar(100),
    LastLoginTime datetime,
    constraint PK_Users primary key(UserID),
    constraint UK_Users_Username UNIQUE(Username),
    constraint CH_Users_Password CHECK(length(users.Pass)>=5)
     );

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `TR_BeforeInsert_Users`
BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF LENGTH(`Pass` ) < 5 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on Pass failed';
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;

Insert into Users(Username, Pass, FullName,lastlogintime) values('ttitto','alabala','Todor', now());
Insert into Users(Username, Pass, FullName,lastlogintime) values('ttitt','ala','Todor', now());
select length(Pass) from users;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within triggers, one must reference columns with either the `NEW` or `OLD` pseudo-table prefix.  In your case:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `TR_BeforeInsert_Users`
BEFORE INSERT ON `users`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF CHAR_LENGTH(NEW.Pass) < 5 THEN
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'check constraint on Pass failed';
    END IF;
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: It worked and solved my problem. Thank you for helping me in this 4 hours problem solving maraton!

Comment: @ttitto: Note also that the task requires you to check that the password is more than 5 *characters* in length, which requires the use of MySQL's [`CHAR_LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length) function.  [`LENGTH()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_length), which you're using, returns the number of *bytes* which could be less than the number of characters if the column is encoded using a multibyte character set.